# Average polygon value

Tags: gdal, zonal-statistics

I have a bitmap that contains a polygon NDVI and nodata space.
How do I get the average value of the polygon only, and not the entire raster.

[image]

Comment: @BERA Yes, I have QGIS, but I have to process a lot of rasters, and this is an intermediate step, so I would like to do without this system.

Comment: What are you open to using?  gdal command-line utilities, gdal c++ apis, gdal python bindings, python packages that use gdal?

Comment: @mikewatt I use  gdal command-line utilities and gdal python bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the nodata value is defined, you could you could do something like this with the Python bindings.  `mask = array != nodata` gives a boolean array which contains `True` for valid pixels and `False` for nodata pixels, and `array[mask]` uses numpy's boolean indexing to return only non-nodata values.

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.Open(path)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
assert nodata is not None
array = band.ReadAsArray()
mask = array != nodata
mean = np.mean(array[mask])
print(mean)
```

Although I would always recommend rasterio over the Python bindings.  You could use boolean indexing as above, or [read it as a masked array](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html) and use [numpy's masked array routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ma.html):

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio


with rasterio.open(path) as f:
    array = f.read(1, masked=True)
    mean = np.ma.mean(array)
    print(mean)
```